# capture the query strings of POST method and turn into dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, http-headers, http-post, query-string

how do i get/capture the query strings of POST method and turn into dictionary in python?
this is the content of request.txt file. FYI the query strings parameter may varies depend on the request file.

---

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://localhost/login
Cookie: __cfduid=dcd3e07532; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiIyYzc0In0%3D; key_session=eyJpdiI6IFmZCJ9

_token=VCXB1YcU3ti&email=testmail%40gmail.com&password=pass12345
```

---

this is my code:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

#read last line
with open("request.txt", "r") as file:
    first_line = file.readline()
    for last_line in file:
        pass
```

---

Is there any best ways to get the query string using split or other ways? without refering to last line in request.txt file? thanks a lot

Comment: is that output came from Acunetix ?

Comment: your question isn't clear for me ? do you just want to read the last line of any output file came from burp-suite into a `dict` ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη. my goal is to parse the query strings into dict. i want to send the query strings as payloads to the request.post . my current way is by reading last line from the request.txt file(burp output), however, what if there are any other lines after the query strings? So, my current way didnt work. hope answer ur question

Comment: are the query string is usually came after Cookie or the first blank line ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη it came after first blank line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from urllib import parse

with open("data.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    goal = lines[lines.index("\n")+1]
    print(dict(parse.parse_qsl(parse.urlsplit(goal).path)))
```

Output:

```
{'_token': 'VCXB1YcU3ti', 'email': 'testmail@gmail.com', 'password': 'pass12345'}
```